# error: 'random' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I'm having difficult using the "random()" function in C++.

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
const int low=15;
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int randomize();
  int point =5,number;
  for(int i=1;i<=4;i++) {
    number=low+random(point);
    cout<<number<<":"; point--;
   }
}
```

The error:

```
error: 'random' was not declared in this scope
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

What does this mean, and how do I correct it?

I'm using the CodeBlock IDE (not sure if that matters).

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Do you mean to use `rand()`?

Comment: what is `random`? i know rand function and for that u need to include `stdlib.h`. Post the Code to be specific.

Comment: #include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
const int low=15;
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int randomize();
    int point =5,number;
    for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        number=low+random(point);
        cout<<number<<":";
        point--;

    }
}

Comment: @uvi As you can see code in comments is ugly and almost unreadable. Please add such information to your question.

Comment: The compiler has already told you what the problem is, this random() thing you are trying to use doesn't exist here.

Comment: @uvi In which of the headerfiles included you think `random()` should be declared??

Answer (score 2):

The function you mean to call is `rand` not `randomize`. Please see [C++ Reference - rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/)

There are a few steps to using the `rand` function. First, you must seed the PRNG (see [Wikipedia - Random Seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed)). This is done using `srand()` (see [C++ Reference - srand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/)).

Once the PRNG is seeded, you may start generating random numbers. These numbers may be anywhere on the range of [0,`RAND_MAX`] where `RAND_MAX` is guaranteed to be no less than 32767 (see [C++ Reference - RAND_MAX](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/)).

In order to limit the range of the returned value to a different maximum, such as 100, use the modulus `%` operator (see [Cprogramming - Modulus Operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)).

Putting this information together, we can modify your code to look like this:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h> 

using namespace std;

const int low=15;

int main( ) 
{ 
    int point = 5; 
    int number = 0;
    int random = 0;

    // Seed the random function first
    srand( 0 );

    for( int i=1; i<=4; i++ ) 
    { 
        random = rand( ) % 100; // Generate a random number on the range [0,100)
        number = low + random; 

        cout<< number << ":" ; 
        point--; 
    } 
}
```

Note that in the sample I provide `0` as the seed. Because of this, the PRNG will generate the same set of random values each execution. If you want to generate different sets of random numbers then provide a different seed. A common practice is to provide the current time so that a new set is generated on every execution.

Seeding with time could resemble

```
#include <time.h>

// ...

srand( time( NULL ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `random` function in the C++ standard library. What were you expceting `random(point)` to return? If it was a random integer between 0 and point - 1, try `rand() % point`. If it was a random float between 0 and point, try `rand() * double(point) / RAND_MAX`